# Javascript onsubmit not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I made html form like this and for some reason the form still gets submitted even though I'm using onsubmit. The handleError() function should set the variable flawless to false if an error occurs and if flawless is false document.myForm.onsubmit should also be set to false and the form shouldn't be submitted. I'm super confused looked at it over and over again and I couldn't find anything wrong. Chrome debugger says there's nothing wrong with so idk... It's 9:40 am where I live so I apologies for every typo i made

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <title>Sign Up</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <style>
                    #error {color:red}
                    #birthday {float:left}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <h6 class="error">* requierd</h6>
            <div>
                    <form action="process_data.php" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="">
                            <table border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Name:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="Name" maxlength="20" pattern="/^[A-Za-z ]+$/" placeholder="Your name"><span id="name_error" class="error"> * </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>E-Mail:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="E-Mail" pattern="/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+)*)|('.+'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/" placeholder="Your E-Mail adress"><span id="email_error" class="error"> * </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Password:</td>
                                            <td><input type="password" id="pw" name="Password" minlength="8" maxlength="63" placeholder="Your password"><span id="pw_error" class="error"> * </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                                            <td><input type="password" id="cpw" name="Confirm Password" minlength="8" maxlength="63" placeholder="Confirm your password"><span id="cpw_error" class="error"> * </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Username:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="Username" pattern="/^[A-Za-z ]+$/" minlength="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="Your username"><span id="username_error" class="error"> * </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Bio:</td>
                                            <td><textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="bio" name="Bio" maxlength="120" placeholder="Something about you"></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Location:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" id="loc" name="Location" pattern="/^[A-Za-z ]+$/" placeholder="Where are you from"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Website:</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" id="url" name="URL" pattern="/^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/" placeholder="Your website"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>Birthday:</td>
                                            <td>
                                                    <div id="birthday">
                                                            <input type="number" min="1" size="2" max="31" id="dob" name="Day of birth" placeholder="day">
                                                            <input type="number" size="2" min="1" max="12" id="mob" name="Month of birth" placeholder="month">
                                                            <input type="number" size="4" min="1900" id="yob" name="Year of birth" placeholder="year"><span id="date_error" class="error"> * </span>
                                                    </div>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                    </form>
            </div>
    <script>
    function handleError(element) {
            var x = element.value, xl = element.value.length;
            var min = element.min, minl = element.minlength;
            var max = element.max, maxl = element.maxlength;
            var cpw = document.getElementById('cpw').value;
            var pw = document.getElementById('pw').value;
            var y = element.name, flawless = true;

        try {
            //Name:
                if (y == "Name") {
                                    if (x == "") throw y + " can't be empty!";
                                    if (xl > maxl) throw y + " must have less than 20 characters!";
                    }
            //E-Mail:
                    else if (y == "E-Mail") {
                                    if (x == "") throw y + " can't be empty!";
                    }
            //Password:
                    else if (y == "Password") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + "input field is still empty!";
                            if (x != cpw) throw "Passwords have to match!";
                            if (xl < minl) throw y + " must have alteast 8 characters!";
                            if (xl > maxl) throw y + " must have less than 63 characters!";
                    }
            //Confirm PW:
                    else if (y == "Confirm Password") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + "input field is still empty!";
                            if (x != pw) throw "Passwords have to match!";
                            if (xl < minl) throw y + " must have alteast 8 characters!";
                            if (xl > maxl) throw y + " must have less than 63 characters!";
                    }
            //Username:
                    else if (y == "Username") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + " is still empty!";
                            if (xl < minl) throw y + " must have alteast 4 characters!";
                            if (xl > maxl) throw y + " must have less than 20 characters!";
                    }
            //Bio:
                    else if (y == "Bio") {
                            if (xl > maxl) throw y + " must have less than 20 characters!";
                    }
            //Birthday:
                    else if (y == "Day of birth") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + " is still empty!";
                            if (x < min) throw y + " is too low!";
                            if (x > max) throw y + " is too high!";
                    }
                    else if (y == "Month of birth") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + " is still empty!";
                            if (x < min) throw y + " is too low!";
                            if (x > max) throw y + " is too high!";
                    }
                    else if (y == "Year of birth") {
                            if (x == "") throw y + " is still empty!";
                            if (x < min) throw y + " is too low!";
                            if (x > max) throw y + " is too high!";
                    }
            }
            catch(err) {
                    switch (y) {
                            case "Name":
                                    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "E-Mail":
                                    document.getElementById('email_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "Password":
                                    document.getElementById('pw_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "Confirm Password":
                                    document.getElementById('cpw_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "Username":
                                    document.getElementById('username_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "Bio":
                                    document.getElementById('bio_error').innerHTML += err;
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            case "Day of birth" || "Month of birth" || "Year of birth":
                                    document.getElementById('date_error').innerHTML += err + " | ";
                                    flawless = false;
                                    break;

                            default:
                                    //code block
                    }
            }
            finally {
                    x = "";
            }
            if (!flawless) document.myForm.onsubmit = false;
    }

    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('name').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('pw').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('cpw').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('username').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('bio').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('dob').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('mob').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('yob').onchange = handleError(this);
    document.getElementById('yob').max = year;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's with 9:40? I was up at 6am... Anyway press F12 and look at the error messages you have in the console. You cannot do `document.myForm.onsubmit = false;` it will do nothing. Instead do `return flawless` in the handle error and do `document.myForm.onsubmit =handleError;` and remove the inline onsubmit=""

Comment: your onSubmit is empty.... take a look

Comment: HTML5 will do automatic page validation,you can make use of it and avoid the checkins in javascript..refer these..http://www.pageresource.com/html5/input-validation-tutorial/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Comment: @mplungjan console says there are none and i tried all the commented methods but they don't work.

Comment: Please look at my answer then. It is the simplest change of your script. It could (and possibly should) be rewritten to work as `document.myForm.onsubmit=function() { are things not ok? return false; return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since a rewrite would be a lot of work, just change

```
if (!flawless) document.myForm.onsubmit = false;
```

to

```
 document.myForm.onsubmit = flawless?null:function() {return false}
```

and have

```
window.onload=fuction() {
  document.myForm.onsubmit = function() {return false}
}
```

to stop immediate submission if nothing changed, i.e. submit button clicked without entering anything